# vim highlight all lines that have marks

Tags: vim

There are plugins that show marks, e.g. [vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) and [ShowMarks](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ShowMarks), but they only show signs at sidebar.

Is there a way to highlight all lines that have marks?

Currently I'm using an expression to do this, for example:

```
:highlight currawong ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred
:match currawong /\%12l\|\%34l\|\%5l/
```

This highlights line 12, 34 and 5.

It's working, but not very convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this command:

```
:highlight currawong ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred
:match currawong /\v.*(%'a|%'b|%'c|%'d).*/
:nmap <F5> :redraw!<CR>
```

It will highlight lines which contains marks: `a-d`.
Type <kbd>F5</kbd> to force a redraw.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is it won't automatically cancel highlight when removing a mark, need to do `:match` again, but already better than my way.

Comment: @Deqing You need to run `:redraw!` to refresh screen.